# Drupal 6 - why Edit node display home page instead from fields.?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

When i try to edit a node with clean url it shows the home page. but the actual url is for the edit node. but when i try with disabled clean url it works fine. can anyone help me with the solution of this. ?

Note: this happens only on the live site not with the localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in settings. need to setup the drupal again.